# Filter within includes in django template

Tags: django

I am utilizing an includes within my template, but would only like to send a splice of the django queryset through the template. I don't want to splice in my view, because this is apart of a larger for loop that will be continually calling the include with different subsections. Here was my wishful thinking:

```
{% for g in gl %}
  {% include 'includes/file.html' with ps=ps|id:g.id %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a filter tag that will receive your queryset and return a filtered one.... you can find details here:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: How would I call the template tag in the include??